# PerSSTableIndexWriter.java:211 - Rejecting value for column payload (analyzed false)

Tags: cassandra

we have Cassandra 3.4.4.
In the system.log we have a lot message like this:

```
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:2] 2020-09-16 13:42:52,916 PerSSTableIndexWriter.java:211 - Rejecting value (size 1.938KiB, maximum 1.000KiB) for column payload (analyzed false) at /opt/cassandra/data/cfd/request-c8399780225a11eaac403f5be58182da/md-609-big SSTable.
```

What are the significance of these messages?
These entries appear several hundred per second, log rotates every minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symptoms you described tell me that you have added a SASI index on the `payload` column of the `cfd.request` table but didn't used to.

Those messages are coming because Cassandra is going through the data trying to index them that the `payload` column has too much data in it. The maximum term size for SASI is 1024 bytes but in the example you posted, the term size was 1.9KB.

If the column only contains ASCII characters, the maximum term length is 1024 characters since each ASCII character is 1 byte. If the column has extended Unicode such as Chinese or Japanese characters, the maximum term length is shorter since each of those take up 3 bytes.

You don't have a SASI analyzer configured on the index (`analyzed false`) so the whole column value is taken up as a single term. If you use the standard SASI analyzer, the column value will get tokenised breaking them up into multiple terms which are shorter and you won't see those indexing failures get logged.

If you're interested in the detailed fix steps, see https://community.datastax.com/questions/8370/. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
After consulting with the developer, I removed the index because he told me that it was not needed.
But the log still says:

INFO  [CompactionExecutor:1] 2020-09-17 14:33:53,491 PerSSTableIndexWriter.java:211 - Rejecting value (size 2.316KiB, maximum 1.000KiB) for column payload (analyzed false) at /opt/cassandra/data/cfd/request-c8399780225a11eaac403f5be58182da/md-609-big SSTable.

What should I do now ?

Comment: The message no longer appears in the log. Maybe the engine took time. Thank you again, you are great.

Comment: That's correct, there's a bit of lag. Also, you noted that you're running C* 3.4.4 but that version doesn't exist. Instead I think you meant C* 3.11.4 so I've submitted an edit to your post. Cheers!

Comment: @ErickRamirez - I would suggest encouraging the OP make that edit, rather than making an assumption on version number (it could be 3.0.4, 3.4, 3.11.4...). Of course, you might be totally right. In general though, best to let someone edit their own question, especially when it comes to specifics such as version numbers.